# Error 503 on SQL/Oracle prodécure execution

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, sql, oracle

I'm facing a problem with the Apache/Tomcat/JDBC/Oracle communication configuration of an application.

Here are all the informations I have at my disposal about the problem :

- A button on the web-app lauches a SQL/Oracle procedure that takes about 5 to 10 minutes to come to an end successfully.
- The application is deployed on two distinct environnements. The Apache/Tomcat server configurations appear to be the same. The physical architecture, instead, is different (memory ressources, etc.)
- On one environnement, when this procedure is lauched, it always aborts after around 5 minutes with an ERROR 503 : "Service Unavailable".

I know there is not a lot of details, but do you have any idea of the reason why such an error occur ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved :

The Configuration file "http.conf" on the Apache server contains the following parameter :

```
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300
```

This default parameter is set to 5 minutes.
I extended this configuration to allow the procedure to terminate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the little information that you provided, I would guess that it is a very intensive procedure since it takes 5-10 minutes to return. I would also guess that the procedure is failing to execute to completion on the server with less memory which is why you are receving the "Service Unavailable" message. If you received a "Request Timed Out" message, then it would be a different case where the procedure could still be running, but didn't have enough time to finish before responding to your client.

Is the amount of memory on the second server significantly different than the amount of memory on the first server?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, the problem has been solved. I just updated the post with the solution.